# iOS 7 beginUpdates endUpdates inconsistent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nsindexpath

**Edit**:
The solution for this answer is related to iOS7 sometimes returning `NSIndexPath` and other times returning `NSMutableIndexPath`. The issue wasn't really related to `begin/endUpdates`, but hopefully the solution will help some others.

---

All - I'm running my app on iOS 7, and I'm running into problems with the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods for a `UITableView`.

I have a tableview that needs to change the height of a cell when touched. Below is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        // If our cell is selected, return double height
        if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
            return 117;
        }

        // Cell isn't selected so return single height
        return 58;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        ChecklistItemCell *cell = (ChecklistItemCell *)[self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.decreaseButton setHidden:NO];
        [cell.increaseButton setHidden:NO];

        // Toggle 'selected' state
        BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

        DLog(@"%@", selectedIndexes);

        DLog(@"is selected: %@", isSelected ? @"yes":@"no");
        // Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
        NSNumber *selectedIndex = @(isSelected);
        selectedIndexes[indexPath] = selectedIndex;

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

The `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods are working pretty inconsistently. The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method gets called correctly on each touch(I thought at first the UI was getting blocked), and the `selectedIndexes` is storing alternating values correctly. The issue is, sometimes I touch a table cell and all the methods are called properly, but the cell height doesn't change. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a change in behavior in iOS7 where index paths are sometimes instances of `NSIndexPath` and other times `UIMutableIndexPath`. The problem is that `isEqual` between these two classes is always going to return `NO`. Thus, you cannot reliably use index paths as dictionary keys or in other scenarios that rely on `isEqual`.

I can think of a couple of viable solutions:

1. Write a method that always returns an instance of `NSIndexPath` and use it to generate keys:

   ```
   - (NSIndexPath *)keyForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       if ([indexPath class] == [NSIndexPath class]) {
           return indexPath;
       }
       return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
   }
   ```
2. Identify rows by the data, not the index path. For example, if your data model is an array of `NSString`, use that string as the key into your `selectedIndexes` map. If your data model is an array of `NSManagedObjects`, use the `objectID`, etc.

I'm successfully using both of these solutions in my code.

**EDIT** Modified solution (1) based on @rob's suggestion of returning `NSIndexPaths` rather than `NSStrings`.

Comment: I applied this solution by making a "strict" indexPath and using that in "forKey" lookups. E.g.: NSIndexPath* strictIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];

Comment: @rob I like that. Updated my answer with a slightly modified variation.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. But I don't understand where to apply @TimothyMoose 's `keyForIndexPath` inside the original posters code. Where would we call this method?

Comment: @Brett The original poster would call the method anytime he reads or writes to the `selectedIndexes` dictionary. For example, instead of `selectedIndexes[indexPath]` he'd do `selectedIndexes[[self keyForIndexPath indexPath]]`

Comment: i have the same problem as @workInAFishBowl but when i checked to see fi [indexPath class] == [NSIndexPath class] would return true or false it always returned true no matter what.. seems like your answer didnt work for me, any thoughts?

Comment: @MrAppleBR I've tested this fix code extensively, so I think you've got some other issue. But could you just try removing the `if` statement entirely? If it still doesn't work, you might want to post a new question and include your view controller code.

Comment: @TimothyMoose it actually worked.. i just removed the if like you said and now its good to go..!! also, are you guys having problems when deleting rows?

Comment: @MrAppleBR no problems deleting rows here. All of our stuff is based on my [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) library if you're interested. There are several sample projects that delete rows (Collapse, Outline & Settings off the top of my head).

Comment: Just curious, how did you find this? Did you read in docs? Testing extensively?...

Comment: @valcanaia just inspected object types in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`endUpdates` shouldn't be called immediately after `beginUpdates`. The latter's documentation states, "Begin a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the receiver." That suggests that it should be called in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `endUpdates` should be called in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: What he's doing has been a well-known trick for animating a cell's row height in prior versions of iOS.

Comment: @TimothyMoose you're assumption is correct. Do you know why it isn't working in iOS7 or do you know work-arounds?