# Issues using NSIndexPath as key in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary, nsindexpath

Is there any particular reason why attempting to store and retrieve a value in an `NSMutableDictionary` using an `NSIndexPath` as a `key` might fail?

I originally attempted to do this in order to store an `NSMutableDictionary` of `UITableViewCell` heights (`self.cellHeights`) for a `UITableView`. Each time you tapped a `UITableViewCell`, that cell would either expand or contract between two different heights based on the value stored in the `NSMutableDictionary` for that particular `indexPath`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSNumber *heightNSNumber = [self.cellHeights objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (!heightNSNumber)
    {
        heightNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0];
        [self.cellHeights setObject:heightNSNumber forKey:indexPath];
    }
    return [heightNSNumber floatValue];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSNumber *heightNSNumber = [self.cellHeights objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (!heightNSNumber)
    {
        heightNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0];
        [self.cellHeights setObject:heightNSNumber forKey:indexPath];
    }

    if ([heightNSNumber floatValue] == 100.0)
    {
        [self.cellHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0] 
                             forKey:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self.cellHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0] 
                             forKey:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

For reasons unknown to me, getting the cell height within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` via `[self.cellHeights objectForKey:indexPath]` works just fine. However, trying to get the cell height within `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` via `[self.cellHeights objectForKey:indexPath]` always returns nil because it seems that the indexPath used to store the height doesn't match the indexPath being used to fetch the cell height, even though they have the same values for `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`. Because of this, a new object for the "same" index path is added to `self.cellHeights` (as evident since `self.cellHeights.count` increases thereafter).

This does *not* happen when you store the cell heights in the NSMutableDictionary using the row (`[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]`) as the key...so that's what I'm doing for now, but I'd like to understand why `indexPath` isn't working as the key.

Answer (score 13):

Although I'm late in the discussion, here's a quick and simple solution that will allow you to use NSIndexPath instances as dictionary keys.

Just **recreate** the indexPath by adding the following line:

```
indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
```

Voilà. `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` uses `NSMutableIndexPath` instances internally (as you would see with a breakpoint). Somehow those instances seem uncooperative with `NSIndexPath` when calculating hash keys.

By converting it back to an `NSIndexPath`, then everything works.

Comment: Holy Moly. This was DRIVING ME MAD. For hours I have been combing the internet trying to figure out why my dictionary was returning nil for an indexPath I KNEW existed. Absolutely maddening. THANKS for posting.

Answer (score 5):

@Jean's answer seems acceptable, but this question has been [answered in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919459/ios-7-beginupdates-endupdates-inconsistent/18920573#18920573). In short, `UITableView` sometimes uses instances of `NSMutableIndexPath` instead of `NSIndexPath` and instances of these two classes are never equal because `[NSMutableIndexPath class] != [NSIndexPath class]`. The workaround is to always generate a key `NSIndexPath` for anything that relies on `isEqual` or `hash`, such as looking up dictionary keys:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)keyForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath class] == [NSIndexPath class]) {
        return indexPath;
    }
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that must be implemented for an object to work reliably as a key for `NSDictionary`, namely `isEqual:`, `hash` and `Copyable` protocol.

I am not very sure that `NSIndexPath` was ever intented to work as a key for dictionaries (because it was made to be an index for arrays).

My guess is that `hash` is not implemented correctly for different instances of the class. Also note that some of the table delegate methods are called with `NSIndexPath` and some with `NSMutableIndexPath`. That's probably making the difference.