# My CellForRowAtInexPath is sending wrong info?

Tags: ios, uitableview

when I call the indexpath of cellForRowAtIndexPath: for deleting the cell it deletes de cell before the selected one... Heres how It works:

I add info to the tableview:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self.tasks insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
    [self.userdefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    [self.userdefaults synchronize];

    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(0) inSection:0];
    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [self.userdefaults synchronize];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];
}
```

And then I edit the info with some gestures from a CocoaControl (MCSwipeTableViewCell):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//This is for deleting a cell
[cell setSwipeGestureWithView:cross color:redColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState2 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {


        [tableView beginUpdates];

        I tried to use this index and didnt work-->//NSIndexPath *myindex = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];

        [self.tasks removeObjectAtIndex:[self keyForIndexPath:indexPath].row];
        [self.userdefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
        [self.userdefaults synchronize];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Cross\" cell");
    }];


}

- (NSIndexPath *)keyForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath class] == [NSIndexPath class]) {
        return indexPath;
    }
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

So when I try to delete It deletes a cell before the one it was selected, I need someones help, thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you need to capture `indexPath` as a local variable.

Comment: Unrelated but FYI - no need to call `synchronize`. And there is no need to use `beginUpdates/endUpdates` if you only call one table view insert/delete/reload.

Comment: @HotLicks The block will retain `indexPath`.

Comment: So I delete the begin and endUpdates? that can be the problem?

Comment: @rmaddy - But the caller will change it.  It needs to be copied.

Comment: @HotLicks `NSIndexPath` is immutable. Once the block keeps its own reference, how can it be changed?

Comment: @user3290977 I simply pointed out that it isn't needed in this case but it isn't hurting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 beginUpdates endUpdates inconsistent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919459/ios-7-beginupdates-endupdates-inconsistent)

Comment: @rmaddy - NSMutableIndexPath is not immutable.

Comment: I Implement the answer of @HotLicks link and I got a crash: 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]' I updated my code so how it looks now

Comment: It works sometimes but after 2 or three deletes It crashes or deletes the wrong selection

Comment: Why not just use [tableView indexPathForCell:cell] in your completion block?

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 is working well, lets see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]` in your completion block to get the appropriate indexPath.

Answer (score -2):

Try using: `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];` instead?